# how to import plugin class in ext js?

Tags: extjs

If I am developing an exts plugin class to be used in a grid. Let us say that the name of the plugin class is GridFilters.js and inside the plugin class, we have : `Ext.namespace("Ext.ux.grid")`
In my SomeGrid.ui.js class, I am doing :

```
SomeGridUi = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
  title: '',
  frame: true,
  loadMask: true,
  cls: 'vline-on',
  flex :1,
  plugins : new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({filters:[
    {type: 'string',  dataIndex: 'someIndex'}
  ]}),
```

It says:

```
Message: 'Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters' is null or not an object
```

I understand, some kind of import needs to be done...but not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you need to add HTML to load `GridFilters.js` file before `SomeGrid.ui.js`.

And your plugin must be of course added to the namespace

```
Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters = ....
```

Comment: So inside SomeGrid.ui.js, we need <html><script>import plugin...</script></html>

Comment: Nope. You need that in the same html, that loads SomeGrid.ui.js. (the same that loads your `ext-all.js` as well. Alternatively, you can try sing `Ext.Loader` class, but I'm not sure how good is that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `<script>` tag for the plugin into HTML - like Mchl sayd - is the simplest solution.

However, when you are developing anything a bit bigger I strongly recommend looking at some kind of dynamic loading solution:

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is probably the closest to a standard in this regard. Used by many-many projects out there.

For ExtJS specifically there is the already mentioned [Ext.Loader](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Loader), but that's probably way too simplistic to do anything serious. Most importantly it doesn't include a tool to build it all into one compact JavaScript file for deployment.

And then there is the promised [ExtJS 4](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system/), that should come with all this built in. But one has to wait for it still...